# Is "star wars" equivalent to "wars of the stars" ? Then how about "world war"?

Tags: idioms, grammatical-number, attributive-nouns, compound-words

I have some questions:

1. Why "star wars" and not "stars wars"?
2. Is "star wars" equivalent to "wars of the stars"? In French it would be "les guerres des etoiles", what about the English version?
3. If question 2 is true, why doesn't "world war" mean "war of the worlds"?

Comment: As an aside, "Star Wars" was originally titled "La Guerre des étoiles" in French. https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars

Comment: Thanks Elian. That's more related to the "wars", one or many. I think "la guerre des étoiles" would translate to "star war". It's the "stars" or "star" and "world" that interests me.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever there is a noun phrase that is made of up two nouns, the first one will always be the base form of the word. That is why we have "dog food" and not "dogs food" even though said "dog food" maybe used to feed more than one dog.

A noun phrase of two nouns holds that the right word is what holds key to the mean, except for noun phrase idioms.

Star Wars is interesting because it is comprised of multiple battles but only one war. Never the less, it is a type of war but occurs across planetary systems. Thus, "star" is a synecdoche to represent the whole of the universe. The word is therefore metaphorical.

Comment: Could you elaborate on ""star" is a synecdoche to represent the whole of the universe. The word is therefore metaphorical" ? Take "bus stop" and "world war" as example. What is the difference between them ?

Comment: I don't think Star is meant to represent the whole of the universe. It's a more a description of where the war takes place - i.e., amongst the stars. Think of it more akin to "Tree Wars" being used to describe jungle warfare.

Comment: I agree with Webreaper on _amongst the stars_. Student fight: fight of/amongst the students.

Comment: Yet we have not explained the difference between _star war_ and _world war_. One is war amongst the stars (many stars), the other is amongst those within a single world.

Comment: @Kenny: he did explain it. When you use a noun to modify another noun, it almost always takes the singular form. Consider *horse race* → race between horses (there have to be more than one to make it a race) and *horse cart* → a cart drawn by a horse (most horse carts are pulled by only one horse). You can't tell how many horses there are in a phrase *horse <noun>*. English is ambiguous this way. What *star war* actually means is a war having something to do with one or more stars.

Comment: Not always true. Dogs home, working mens club, sports car. Covered here before.

Comment: @Edwin: *dog's home* and *working men's club* are possessives with the apostrophes elided; *sports car* is one of the exceptions covered by the *almost always* in my comment above (but now I see that you probably were replying to the answer, which did say *always*).

Comment: @Peter Yes I was. But _dogs home_ (etc) are of the same form, Npl(att) + N, no matter what their etymology. Though one might have problems analysing open compounds including _mens_ and _childrens_.

Comment: @PeterShor : _horse cart_ can mean cart drawn by horseS _in general_. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse-drawn_vehicle . It does not specify the number of horses but it can be more than one. Similar to bus stop, train station, fish tank, etc. All are "A for Bs (plural) in general, can contain one or more of Bs"_World war_ unambigously refers to only one world.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare [Vietnam War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnam_War) with [Korean War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_War), you can notice there is one difference between them. *Vietnam* is a name of the country while *Korean* is an adjective relating to North or South Korea or its people or language. You don't call the war in Vietnam **Vietnamese War** because it is the way it is as the [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Vietnam+War%2C+Vietnamese+War&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CVietnam%20War%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CVietnamese%20War%3B%2Cc0) clearly shows.

However, both compound nouns carry the same characteristic. The two wars were fought by Vietnamese and Korean people respectively within the boundaries of each country even though they were supported by other countries such as the former USSR, China and the U.S., etc.

1. Star Wars simply means **multiple (more than two) wars among (fought by) stars**. The compound noun is made in the same way as Vietnam war and Korean War. Then, why not **starry war** like Korean war? The word [*starry*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/starry) according to Online Oxford Dictionary doesn't have the right connotation as it means:

> Full of or lit by stars, resembling a star in brightness or shape, or
>   (informal) relating to stars in the world of entertainment

2. The producers and director chose **Star Wars** as they can choose whatever they like with their [artistic licence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license) also known as poetic license. It is up to them to choose among **Star Wars**, **Wars of Stars**, **Wars of the Stars** and **Starry Wars**, etc. Therefore, your second question is not very meaningful, but I would say it is equivalent to **Wars of Stars**
3. **World War** is compounded in the same way as Vietnam War or Korean War. The war was fought by many countries almost **all over the world**, not in one specific country. Then, why not **Worldly War**? Because people decided to call it **World War** and it was used by many people.

As explained in the other post, we can make compound nouns (or noun phrases) that include a noun modified by adjectives or noun adjuncts. And the noun adjuncts (first noun) are used as if they were an adjective. That's why only the second noun takes the plural form as in *Star Wars*.

You can visit the following [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Compound_nouns) to learn more about compound nouns.

**Edit**:  The noun adjuncts *World* and *Vietnam* can mean the places where the wars were fought. The World War was fought in many countries **in the world**. That's why it is called **World War**. The Vietnam War was fought in Vietnam. That's why it is called **Vietnam War**.

Comment: Interesting point regarding _Vietnam war_ and _Korean war_. I have seen similar in several occasions. Yet I am rather intrigued by the relation _star war_ and _world war_, not _star war/starry war_ and _world war/worldly war_. As you mentioned, which is also my question, _star war_ happens within _many_ stars fighting. _world war_ are those within a _single_ world. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: As I made it in bold above, the noun adjuncts (World, Vietnam) can mean the placse where the wars were fought. The World War was fought in many countries in the world. That's why it is called "World War". The Vietnam War was fought in Vietnam. That's why it is called "Vietnam War". I will edit the post using this comment.

Comment: Then what happen to _star war_, it does not fall into either category of _Korean war_ nor _world war_ : war happening in X.

Comment: @Kenny Contrast a sleeping bag with a sleeping baby. English doesn't work in just one way. The former means a bag for your sleeping in a tent, the latter means a baby who is sleeping now. Smoking room vs. smoking dish.

Comment: Aren't we discussing noun+noun and not adjective+noun because we seem to have shifted to _world war vs worldly war_ . I agree on this difference. But what intrigue me is that, following your reasoning, _world war_ : place where it take place - the SINGLE world. star war : it happens in 1 star. I am interested in why _star war_ refers to many stars and ww is 1 single world

Comment: @Kenny **And the noun adjuncts (first noun) are used as if they were an adjective**. Adjectives don't have plural forms because they are adjectives. Noun adjuncts functioning as an adjective doesn't take plural forms. When you buy an engine oil, can it be used for only one engine?

Comment: That "Adjectives don't have plural forms" we have agreed as well. I am not trying to argue _worldS war" vs _world war_. It's _world war_ and _star war_, both single noun(as adj as you have said)+noun. _engine oil_ is oil used for _engineS_ in general. Not one specific engine. _star war_ for starS. _world war_ is not for _worldS_ but only single unique _world_.

Comment: @Kenny Your question is closed as duplicate. Read the duplicate and study it yourself. I am done.